# Moving all values one up and putting new value to the bottom

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array[8] and freeIndex = 0. How can I add all the values in the array up one position and add a new value to the last position? Would the simplest answers be

```
amuletHolder[8] = amuletHolder[7];
amuletHolder[7] = amuletHolder[6];
amuletHolder[6] = amuletHolder[5];
amuletHolder[5] = amuletHolder[4];
amuletHolder[4] = amuletHolder[3];
amuletHolder[3] = amuletHolder[2];
amuletHolder[2] = amuletHolder[1];
```

How to add the new value to the bottom?

Comment: Do you mean "How can I MOVE all the values in the array up one position", instead of "How can I add all the values in the array up one position?"

Comment: You could use a linked list instead of an array - then it would be faster. If performance does not matter, then the simple answer would be to loop over it and move everything one after the other by assigning it.

Comment: It's seems you want to implement a queue.

Answer (score 2):

With a for loop:

```
for (int i = length - 1; i > 0; --i) {
    amuletHolder[i] = amuletHolder[i - 1];
}
amuletHolder[0] = newValue;
```

Side note: If you array is length 8 valid index are 0-7. Your code will throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on the first line.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you need an array?

A LinkedList has a lot of these capabilities built in and can be done quite dynamically something like this:

```
updateList(list, delId, addtId, newItem){
    list.remove(delId);
    list.add(addId, newItem);
}
```

or a Queue would be better if you strictly go FIFO

```
updateQueue(queue, newItem){
  queue.remove();
  queue.add(newItem);
}
```

EDIT:
But if you really need an array and need to keep [0] empty I don't see a problem with what you have. It does use a couple more lines than the loop suggested by others but if you only have 8 elements it isn't significant.

to add the new item and leave [0] empty just add `array[1]=newItem;`

```
array[7]=array[6];
array[6]=array[5];
array[5]=array[4];
array[4]=array[3];
array[3]=array[2];
array[2]=array[1];
array[1]=newItem;
```

Or use a loop as others have suggested; something like:

```
for(int i=7;i>1;i--){
  array[i]=array[i-1];
}
array[1]=newItem;
```